# Error '1004'- Unable to Get Sum Property of the worksheet function Class with defined range variable

Tags: excel, loops

Not sure why I'm getting an error on certain worksheets and not others. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code line that is getting the error:

```
    If Rng2.Value = 0 Or Rng2.Value = "" Or Rng2.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Define" Or WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng2.EntireRow) = Rng2.Value _
        And Rng2.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "" Then
```

The code is part of this loop:

```
For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
    If Rng2.Value = 0 Or Rng2.Value = "" Or Rng2.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Define" Or Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng2.EntireRow) = Rng2.Value _
        And Rng2.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "" Then
        Rng2.Value = Rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next
```

`Rng2` is not a defined range it's a set range variable. `WorkRng2` is a set range and a defined variable

Comment: try `Rows(Rng2.Row)` instead of `Rng2.EntireRow`

Comment: Do you have any error values?

Comment: How do you declare `Rng2`?  Doing `WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng2.entireRow)` worked for me, doing `Dim rng2 as Range // set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`.  Since you're saying it works on some sheets, and not others, I think you probably are not declaring `rng2` with the worksheet it's on?  See how I did `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(...)`? You should be sure to declare your `Rng2` similarly.

Comment: I found it, it was a value error, still now sure why the text is causing it though...

Comment: @BruceWayne `rng2` is only my cell range that i'm using for the loop. it is a public variable i've declared but is not set.

Comment: @MikeMann - Sorry, I see you use it in the loop. I meant to ask about `WorkRng2`.

Comment: @BruceWayne on yea, `WorkRng2` is a variable I set with an input box

Comment: @MikeMann - Did you get the error worked out? I assume you want the inputbox input to be something like `A1:A100`? Entered exactly as a range?  Did you `Dim WorkRng2 as String`? How'd you declare it?

Comment: yea I worked it out. Than you for your help. It was a value error, i just wrote in `on error resume next` I couldn't figure out why the text was causing the value error in the sum function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, this code works fine. I was getting an error because I had an `#value` error in the sum range.